# tsserver: Error processing request (No Project)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript2.0

When working on a TypeScript (v2.0+) project within 'Visual Studio Code' (v1.5.3) I get the following error:

```
[Error - 10:03:50 AM] 'format' request failed with error.
Error processing request. No Project.
Error: No Project.
...
```

I restarted visual-studio-code with verbose logging.

```
export TSS_LOG='-level verbose -file <my-home>/tss.log'
```

This gives a bit more information:

```
Info 1233 request: {"seq":522,"type":"request","command":"format","arguments":{"file":"/<my_project>/src/ts/<the-file>.ts","line":1,"offset":1,"endLine":616,"endOffset":1}}

Err 1234  Exception on executing command {"seq":522,"type":"request","command":"format","arguments":{"file":"/<my_project>/src/ts/<the-file>.ts","line":1,"offset":1,"endLine":616,"endOffset":1}}:
No Project.
Error: No Project.
    at Errors (<my_global_node>/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:50793:32)
    at ts.server.ts.server (<my_global_node>/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:50795:11)
    at ts (<my_global_node>/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:51775:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<my_global_node>/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:51776:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)

Info 1235 response:        
{"seq":0,"type":"response","command":"format","request_seq":522,"success":false,"message":"Error processing request. No Project.
Error: No Project.
    at Errors (/home/fred/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:50793:32)
    at ts.server.ts.server (/home/fred/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:50795:11)
    at ts (/home/fred/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:51775:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/fred/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:51776:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)"}
```

Does tsserver believe I do not have a project?

I have both a 'tsconfig.json' and 'jsconfig.json' file at the project directory root.
I do have a 'tasks.json' that runs tsc.
I can stimulate tsserver with other requests with a similar result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [tsserver.js source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/server/server.ts#L182)

```
$ export TSS_LOG='-level verbose -file <my-home>/tss.log'
$ code
```

The verbose log file holds the answer but not reported as an error.

```
Info 2    Config file name: /<my-project>/src/ts/jsconfig.json
Err 3     Exception on executing command {"seq":0,"type":"request","command":"open","arguments":{"file":"<my-project>/src/ts/<a-class-file>.ts","fileContent":"..."}}: Unexpected end of input
<stack-trace>
```

The problem was that there was an empty 'jsconfig.json' file near the top of the 'src' tree ('src/ts/jsconfig.json'). 
This caused the search for the project root much too low in the file hierarchy. Specifically, the 'tsconfig.json' file was not found resulting in a 'No Project' error.

The executeCommand() function returned undefined, which happens when the associated handler cannot find the project containing the file. 
The files are associated with the project via the 'files' or 'include' options in the 'tsconfig.json'.
The 'tss.log' file should contain 'Info' messages about the files that are opened. Make sure all of the files you care about are opened, in particular check the locations of the 'Config file name' to make sure you are getting the correct files.

This problem did not surface with 'tsc' as it does not consider 'jsconfig.json' as an indicator for a project.

A typical log file should look more like this:

```
Info 0    request: {"seq":0,"type":"request","command":"open","arguments":{"file":"/<my-project>/src/ts/folder1/ClassA.ts","fileContent":"..."}}
Info 1    Search path: /<my-project>/src/ts/folder1
Info 2    Config file name: /<my-project>/tsconfig.json
Err 3     Add recursive watcher for: /<my-project>
Err 4     Add recursive watcher for: /<my-project>/src/ts
Info 5    Opened configuration file /<my-project>/tsconfig.json
Info 6    Project (configured) 0
/<node-root>/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts
/<my-project>/node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts
...a list of all the project files...

-----------------------------------------------
Open file roots of inferred projects:
Open files referenced by inferred or configured projects:
Open file roots of configured projects:
/<my-project>/src/ts/folder1/ClassA.ts
Perf 7    Async elapsed time (in milliseconds): 1060.9415
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you are getting and ignoring this warning:
[image]

I added the dist folder to tsconfig exclude, which solved the "no project" error and the warning.

```
  "exclude": [
    ".git",
    "node_modules",
    "**/dist/*",
    "**/node_modules/*",
  ]
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I noticed that I was having this error in one React project but not the other, so I simply restarted command line and VSCode. For some reason it worked after that.